# How to update some part of the complex dictionary value in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, c#-2.0

My dictionary declared as below

```
    public static Dictionary<object, DataInfo> DataDic = new Dictionary<object, DataInfo>(); 

    public class DataInfo
    {
        public string DSPER;       // Data Sample Period
        public int TOTSMP;      // Total Samples to be made
        public int REPGSZ;      // Report Group Size
        public List<int> IDList;   // Array List to collect all the enabled IDs
    }
```

Function `InitDataDic` Called below, How can I write the code of the dictionary `.Remove()` and `.Add()` after reassign tdi.TOTSMP = 0 under `true` condition in a simply way.

```
public void InitDataDic (object objid, DataInfo datainfo, int totsmp)
{
    DataInfo tdi = new DataInfo(); 
    object trid = objid;
    tdi = datainfo; 

    if (DataDic.ContainsKey(trid) == true)
    {
        DataDic.Remove(trid);  // here, i mentioned above
        tdi.TOTSMP = 0;
        DataDic.Add(trid, tdi);  // here, i mentioned above
    }
    else
    {
        tdi.TOTSMP = topsmp;  
        DataDic.Add(trid, tdi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Has anyone suggested to you to call the field `DataSamplePeriod` instead of `DSPER` (which is unreadable and cryptic), and similarly for all the others?

Comment: @Timwi, The short `DSPER` comes from SEMI E5 Standard Manual. Sure It is a little unreadable and cryptic. Actually it matched the defined parameter from the Standard Manual very well. Thank you.

Comment: So you’re perpetuating someone else’s mistake instead of taking the initiative to fix it where you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add/remove from dictionary if you want to update the object (of ref type) in dictionary - just update the object.

```
if (DataDic.TryGetValue(trid, out tdi)
{
   // already exists in dict, tdi will be initialized with ref to object from dict
   tdi.TOTSMP = 0;   // update tdi
}
else
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: Finially, I found another more simply solution as `DataDic[trid].TOTSMP = tdi.TOTSMP` to update the exist dictionary value.